# Routing to same component with different parameter working on double click only

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, ngxs

I'm working on an application where I have a component - 'A', which creates forms dynamically and then I use this component in another component - 'B' to create the forms.
Now I navigate to 'B' component with parameter as 'test' and also to same component 'B' with different parameters like 'test/1'.

Problem: When I click on the button to navigate to 'B' component with different parameters then it doesn't work on single click though URL changes. I'll have to click on it twice.

Also, I'm using NGXS to set the data in the component so I don't require the param values to render the component. The values are getting populated alright.

I've also noticed that for Wizard component without parameter routing (which is working fine), ngOnInit is called twice but when routing is performed with parameter then it's called only once.

Routing Module:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
      path: '',
      redirectTo: 'home',
      pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: 'home',
    component: HomeComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'wizard',
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        component: WizardComponent,
        pathMatch: 'full'
      },
      {
        path: ':id',
        component: WizardComponent,
      }
    ],
    runGuardsAndResolvers: 'always'
  },
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {
      onSameUrlNavigation: 'reload'
    })
  ],
  exports: [
    RouterModule
  ]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
export const routingComponents = []
```

Code to route to desired url:

```
editQuestion(question: Question){
    this.boolEditBtnClick = true;
    this._store.dispatch(new SetSelectedItem(item));
    this._route.navigate(['wizard', item.Id]);
  }
```

Wizard Component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-test-wizard',
  templateUrl: './test-wizard.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./test-wizard.component.css']
})
export class WizardComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private _testService: NewTetstService, private _fb: FormBuilder, private _route: Router) { 
    this._route.routeReuseStrategy.shouldReuseRoute = () => false;
  }

  formName: string;
  regConfig: ItemControlBase[];

  @Select(ItemState.getSelectedItem) selectedItem: Observable<Item>;
  item:Item = {};

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.stage = this._testService.getStageInfo();
    this.regConfig = this._testService.getMapping(this.stage['Mapping']);
    this.formName = this.stages[0]['Id'].toLowerCase();
    this.newForm = this.createFormGroup(this.formName);
      this.selectedItem.subscribe(item => {
        if (item) {
          this.item = item;
        }
      })
  }

}
```

Comment: There is an options block in `RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {onSameUrlNavigation: 'reload',})`

Comment: Hi Sergey, I have done that but that's not helping.

Comment: Can you show us how you are performing url changes?

Comment: Also, if you are using the same component for `''` path and `:id` path it's may be worth to combine them in a single `:id`

Comment: I have added some more code. I'll try to add the component code as well.

Comment: How can I combine both of them in one? Sending Id as blank for ' ' ?

Comment: You don't have to send it at all. It's just your parameter `id` wouldn't have any value. Meaning `wizzard/1` is almost the same as `wizzard/` since in second case `id` would be `null` or `undefined` not sure which one.

Comment: Hi Sergey, tried this as well and it's not working.

Comment: Have you tried to debug your routing process via subscribing to the router events end printing them in console? Also I don't understand what doesn't work in you case. Whether your route is not being updated or your form is stale. If the second case is yours then you should subscribe to the router params change in OnInit lifecycle and rebuild your form on each param update. Another thing you can try is to replace `['wizard', item.Id]` with `['./', item.id]`

Comment: so the problem that I'm facing is: There is a dynamic form that I have created (a component) and a button "Add New" which should open the blank form and an "Edit" which should load the same form but data populated. When I click on Add New button then the form is loading correctly but when I click on "Edit" button the URL changes but the form doesn't load and when I click on it again then the form loads correctly with the data. So, I have to click twice to load the edit form. Also, as I mentioned, I noticed that for "Add New", ngOnInit is called twice - one with 'add' routing id & second blank.

Comment: Subscribe to url params then and change your form when they change. StackBlitz example would be really helpful

Comment: Hi Sergey, this is resolved but thanks for your answers. It helped me in organizing the routes correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Got it resolved myself. It was a silly mistake at my end.
Problem: Wrong placement of .
I placed this in app.html and below the home component (consisting of header and sidebar) like below:
**app.html**:

```
<app-home></app-home>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

**Solution**:

```
<app-home><router-outlet></router-outlet></app-home>
```